# Using ng-repeat in order to iterate over object properties and ordering by value instead of key with ng 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am in reference to the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) about `ngRepeat` and iterating over object properties which states:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

> You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define
>   the order of keys returned for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular
>   1.3 the ngRepeat directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)

Say I have the following object:

```
var myObj = {FOO: 0, BAR: 1};
```

and want it to be ordered by value (i.e. `0` & `1`) instead of keys. How can this be achieved with angular? (I use angular 1.3 by the way).

I have tried:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj | orderBy:value"
```

But it does not work...

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Before 1.4 angular ordered them always alphabetically and you don't have control over it, you'll have to convert it to an array in a filter or before you get it to the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Just as with filter, orderBy works with arrays only. One simple solution is to use a function that returns an array from an object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/>
<ul ng-init="nameArray=objArray(names)">
  <li ng-repeat="x in nameArray | filter:searchText | orderBy: 'value.name'">
    {{x.value.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.searchText='';
    $scope.names = {
  "1": {
       "name": "some"
  },
  "2": {
       "name": "values"
  },
  "3": {
        "name": "are"
  },
  "4": {
       "name": "there"
  },
  "5": {
        "name": "here"
  }
    };
$scope.objArray=function (obj) {
    var result=[];
    for (var key in obj) {
        result.push({
            key: key,
            value: obj[key]
        });
    }
    return result;
}


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best and elegant solution is to make a filter that changes your object into an array. Therefore you can reuse it thought all your project in your template without coding any js.

Here is what the filter would look like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').filter('toArray', toArray);

    toArray.$inject = [];

    function toArray() {
        return toArrayFilter;
        function toArrayFilter(input) {
            if (angular.isArray(input)) return input;
            var list = [];
            angular.forEach(input, iterateProperty, list);
            return list;
            function iterateProperty(elt, key) {
                this.push({ key: key, value: elt });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

and here is how you would use it in your html template:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in myObject | toArray | orderBy:value">
    {{element.key}}:
    <pre>{{element.value | json}}</pre>
</div>
```